# Pac-Man character moving right when pressing the `"Up arrow"` key bind

Tags: python, python-turtle

So, i was making a pac-man game, i was setting up the keybinds to make the character move. When i hit the `"Up"` button, The Character moves right instead of moving up.

I used this code to move the pac-man character:

```
import turtle

# draw a window with turtle for the pac-man game

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Pac-Man")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# create a turtle for the pac-man

pacman = turtle.Turtle()
pacman.speed(0)
pacman.shape("circle")
pacman.color("white")
pacman.penup()

# create the keybinds for the pacman WASD using a def

def w():
    pacman.forward(20)

def a():
    pacman.left(90)

def s():
    pacman.forward(-20)

def d():
    pacman.right(90)

# loop

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(w, "Up")
wn.onkey(a, "Left")
wn.onkey(s, "Down")
wn.onkey(d, "Right")

# while true window loop

while True:
    wn.update()
    if pacman.xcor() > 280 or pacman.xcor() < -280:
        pacman.right(180)
        if pacman.ycor() > 280:
            pacman.left(180)
```

Also, I would like to know if the code above is complete.

Comment: Maybe `.forward()` means right? Do the other 3 keys work correctly?

Comment: nope only the `left` and `right` keybinds work with the `up` and `down` keys.

Comment: The `up` key moves your pac-man in whatever direction it's currently facing - which I believe will be to the right, by default.

Comment: Try checking this out as it's contrary to what I would expect at least. It seems that `.left()` and `.right()` just set it's rotation but don't move it. Forward goes in the "currently facing" direction move.https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.forward

Comment: The [tag:pygame] is only for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), but not in general for questions about games written with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html), I see that "forward" is not mean to go left,right or any other axis, it only move toward the direction the turtle is facing at the present time.
In your case I don't think this is the right way to do it, even for the "d" key per example, you turtle will turn 90 degrees clockwise each time you press "d" key.

In the beginning, the turtle is facing east when it's created, you can use setheading() :

```
# Up
def w():
   pacman.setheading(0) # north
   pacman.forward(20)

# Down
def w():
   pacman.setheading(180) # south
   pacman.forward(20)

# Left
def w():
   pacman.setheading(270) # west
   pacman.forward(20)

# Right
def w():
   pacman.setheading(90) # east
   pacman.forward(20)
```

Please check the website, depending on your mode, the degrees can change.
Hope it help.